# Converting AVVideoComposition initializer to Nativescript

Tags: javascript, objective-c, nativescript

Looking for some help on porting this objective-c class method to JS/nativescript.. every variation I've tried has resulted in a `TypeError: undefined is not a function...`

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avvideocomposition/1389556-init

Which I've tried to write in JS as:

```js
const videoComp = AVVideoComposition.alloc().initWithAssetApplyingCIFiltersWithHandler(asset, (request) => { ... });

//OR
const videoComp = AVVideoComposition.alloc().initAssetApplyingCIFiltersWithHandler(asset, (request) => { ... });

//OR
const videoComp = AVVideoComposition.alloc().initAssetApplyingCIFiltersWithHandlerApplier(asset, (request) => { ... });

//OR
const videoComp = new AVVideoComposition(asset, (request) => { ... });
```

to name a few. essentially, I am trying to port this code to nativescript/JS:

```
let blurRadius = 6.0
let asset = AVAsset(url: streamURL)
let item = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset)
item.videoComposition= AVVideoComposition(asset: asset) { request in
    let blurred = request.sourceImage.clampedToExtent().applyingGaussianBlur(sigma: blurRadius)
    let output = blurred.clampedToRect(request.sourceImage.extent)
    request.finish(with: output, context: nil)
}
```

found in this blog post: https://willowtreeapps.com/ideas/how-to-apply-a-filter-to-a-video-stream-in-ios

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should look something like this with JavaScript / Typescript,

```
let blurRadius = 6.0;
let asset = AVAsset.assetWithURL(streamURL);
let item = AVPlayerItem.alloc().initWithAsset(asset);
item.videoComposition = AVVideoComposition.videoCompositionWithAssetApplyingCIFiltersWithHandler(asset, request => {
    let blurred = request.sourceImage.imageByClampingToExtent().imageByApplyingGaussianBlurWithSigma(blurRadius);
    let output = blurred.imageByClampingToRect(request.sourceImage.extent);
    request.finishWithImageContext(output, null);
});
```

**Note:** The code is untested and merely a translation of given native code. Make use of [tns-platform-declarations](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tns-platform-declarations) for IntelliSense support.

Comment: this looks like it works, thanks! It appears the main mistake I made was following apple's Swift documentation when converting the APIs, instead of the Objective-C docs, which is what nativescript supports.